# Como hago para que me suba la imagen tambien a firestore - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

******los "input" name y price  me guardan sin problemas a firestore de firebase  pero ahora necesito subir una imagen tambien pero no he podido.

He intentado de muchas formas pero no sube la imagen solo quedan guardados los input name y price.  En el momento que guardo toda la información de los input van a firestore sin problemas menos el campo imagen y necesito que quede la imagen también suba y quede guardada. 

he intentado de muchas formas pero todavía no he podido lograr que guarde, y si la envió así como esta solo guarda la ruta y no mas.******

```
function Contenido() {

const[image,setImage] = useState('')
const[name,setName] = useState('')
const[price,setPrice] = useState(0)
const[error,setError] = useState('')
const[usuario, setUsuario] = useState([])

const setUsuarios = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  
const usuario = {
    image:image,
    name:name,
    price:Number(price)
}

try{
  const data = await store.collection('productos').add(usuario)

}catch(e){

}

}


    return (
            <div className="content-wrapper">
    
    <div className="content-header">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row mb-2">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <h4 className="m-0">CONTENIDO</h4>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <section className="content">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        
        <div className="row">
        
          <div className="col-md-6">

                <h2>Formulario de usuarios</h2>  
                <form onSubmit={setUsuarios} className="form-group">

                    <input value={name} onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Introduce el nombre" />
                    <input value={price} onChange={(e)=>{setPrice(e.target.value)}} type="number" className="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Introduce el precio" />
                    

                    <input onChange={(e)=>{setImage(e.target.value)}} className="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" />
                 

                    <input type="submit" value="registrar" className="btn btn-dark btn-block mt-3" />

                </form> 

                {
                   error ? 

                   (
                       <div>
                           <p>{error}</p>
                       </div>
                   )
                   :

                   (
                       <span></span>
                   )

                }
       
          </div>


          <div className="col-md-6">
       
           <h2>Lista de tu agenda</h2>
              
       
          </div>

         
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </section>
    
  </div>
    )
   }

export default Contenido
```

Answer (score 1):

para empezar te recomiendo que subas las imágenes a storage de firebase, xq sino estarías subiendo un objeto que seria la imagen.

aquí te enseño como importar storage:

```
import firebase from '@lib/firebase.config'; // en ves de esto pondrías la config de tu firebase
```

const storage = firebase.storage(); // asi  llamamos al storage

y este seria el resultado:

```
import firebase from '@lib/firebase.config';
```

const storage = firebase.storage();

function Contenido() {

```
const[image,setImage] = useState('')
const[name,setName] = useState('')
const[price,setPrice] = useState(0)
const[error,setError] = useState('')
const[usuario, setUsuario] = useState([])

const setUsuarios = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  

    // antes de guardar la info ala db hacemos la subida de la imagen a storage
    let urlImage = ''; // aqui se guardara lka url de la imagen 
    try {
        const nameFile = image.name;
        const ref = 'imageformulario/'; //esta sera la direccion base de la ruta al guardar la imagen en storage
        const refDB = storage.ref(`${ref}${nameFile}`); // concatenamos la ruta con el nombre y ala ves le decimos donde lo ira a guardar en storage
        const snap = await refDB.put(file); // aqui subimos la imagen ala ruta especificada
        if (snap.state === 'success') { // si se subio la imagen entrara aqui
            const url = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL(); // obtenemos la url de la imagen
            urlImage = url; // seteamos el valor de la url ala variable
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
    }




    const usuario = {
        image:urlImage, // y aqui ya estaria
        name:name,
        price:Number(price)
    }
    
    try{
        const data = await store.collection('productos').add(usuario)
    
    }catch(e){
    
    }

}


    return (
            <div className="content-wrapper">
    
    <div className="content-header">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row mb-2">
          <div className="col-sm-6">
            <h4 className="m-0">CONTENIDO</h4>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     
    <section className="content">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        
        <div className="row">
        
          <div className="col-md-6">

                <h2>Formulario de usuarios</h2>  
                <form onSubmit={setUsuarios} className="form-group">

                    <input value={name} onChange={(e)=>{setName(e.target.value)}} type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Introduce el nombre" />
                    <input value={price} onChange={(e)=>{setPrice(e.target.value)}} type="number" className="form-control mt-3" placeholder="Introduce el precio" />
                    

                    <input onChange={(e)=>{setImage(e.target.files[0])}} className="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" />
                 

                    <input type="submit" value="registrar" className="btn btn-dark btn-block mt-3" />

                </form> 

                {
                   error ? 

                   (
                       <div>
                           <p>{error}</p>
                       </div>
                   )
                   :

                   (
                       <span></span>
                   )

                }
       
          </div>


          <div className="col-md-6">
       
           <h2>Lista de tu agenda</h2>
              
       
          </div>

         
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </section>
    
  </div>
    )
   }

export default Contenido
```

Answer (score 0):

Al utilizar archivos locales se obtiene su información a traves de event.target.files. Esto es un arreglo de archivos seleccionados.

Si permite al usuario subir un archivo prueba esto:

```html
<input onChange={(e)=> {setImage(e.target.files[0])}} className="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" />
```

Si permite al usuario subir un multiples archivos prueba esto:

```html
<input onChange={(e)=> {setImage(e.target.files)}} className="form-control" type="file" id="formFile" />
```

Comment: pero solo añadiendo lo del input no funciona , que mas tocaria modificar para que guarde ?